# Blender 2.8: Texture doesn't show up in Shading tab / UV Unwrap

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have the problem that my texture is showing in Lookdev in the UV Unwrap tab but as soon as I switch to the Shading tab (still in Lookdev) it is gone.

Testing it with a new created box works.
Switching to edit mode shows the texture as well.

I attached a image explaining the problem with visuals:[image]

Thank you in advance,
Lino

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your image, below:
the first one is in UV Editor and the second one is in Image Editor, that's why the second one doesn't have the UV's, check out the red arrows.
Hope that helps.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: You where talking about the texture on the model, well, not sure without the blend file, but sometimes this happens to me, i think is a bug, because once i render one  (F12) and go back, everything works. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for searching for an answer with me.
I noticed that the meshes which did not show the texture correctly had boolean modifiers on them. 
[image]

I used the KIT OPS kitbashing add-on on those meshes. I 'm not able to get rid of those modifiers, not by applying them, nor using Object - Convert to - Mesh from Curve/...

**The only solution is to make a duplicate of that mesh.**